# change obscure charset or font in ubuntu server console

Tags: command-line, fonts, character-set

When I opened a log file in my Ubuntu server, my server font changed to obscure character according to this picture:

[image]

How can I restore it to the regular font?

Comment: Have you tried `reset`  (a command that re-initializes the terminal)

Comment: i cant restart my server, that should be on service

Comment: the `reset` command only resets the terminal (without touching any values you've set in it; it's for what you want to do right now).  look for yourself, ie. `man reset`  ; ie. it's **not** related to the `reboot` or `shutdown` commands

Comment: whats that command ?

Comment: the command is `reset`.   It's a terminal command to reset after you `cat` a binary file, or send wrong escape codes and screw the terminal up; it resets the terminal display to normal character set.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `reset` command, ie. just type `reset` into your terminal to reset.

The command `clear` could also work, but it's primary function is to clear the display, where `reset` is really what you want.

It's really useful if you're coding and using escape characters to change something in the terminal by make a typo & screw something up, or you `cat` a binary file and find yourself in the same position.

*`clear` was introduced in 1979 because it was common for terminals to be of different brand and use different escape sequences (VT52, VT100 etc). `reset` is another variation*

Comment: the `reset` command dosen,t work

Answer (score 0):

I know its funny but associate on some instruction on other solution I try to open some file with `nano` and terminal CHARSET have been changed to default view.
I don't know why and not any idea on this problem.